# Will dereferencing an r-value reference do anything?

Tags: c++, pointers

So let's say I have this code:

```
std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = std::make_unique<int>(10);

int val = *std::move(ptr);

// Anything using ptr after
```

I know that std::move gives us an r-value reference to the unique_ptr, and I don't think dereference will steal the resources from ptr like a move assignment operator would, so would this code be any different at all without the std::move?

Like if I wanted the resources allocated for ptr to be freed after its value was set into val, would this achieve that?

Comment: sd::move doesn't do anything at all. It is always just a typecast (that will help the compiler select the correct assignment operation on the type on the left). E.g. move assignment in case of a class

Comment: The `std::move` is only called that because `std::permission_granted_to_suck_out_the_innards_leaving_behind_a_dessicated_husk_of_an_object_only_suitable_for_destruction_or_reassignment` was considered — by some — to be too verbose.

Comment: @Ejay Autocomplete might have helped their cause but in the name of clarity (and brevity) "rvalue_cast" would have been a better choice IMHO (did you miss the memo? :)

Comment: The syntax for what you are trying to do here, i.e. actually move ownership in the expression, would be `*auto(std::move(ptr))` in C++23 or `*std::unique_ptr<int>(std::move(ptr))` before that. But as the answer already mentions, it can be expressed much clearer by just calling `.reset()` after the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out if `*std::move(ptr)` does anything to the unique pointer, you need to read documentation for `std::unique_ptr::operator*` (for example here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*). You will find it has only one overload:

```
typename std::add_lvalue_reference<T>::type operator*() const
noexcept(noexcept(*std::declval<pointer>()));
```

It is a `const` method, so it cannot modify the unique pointer.

Ergo, in general `std::move` is just a cast, here it has no effect. You get a reference to the unique pointer, and then `*` dereferences the unique pointer, and a copy of the contained `int` gets assigned to `val`. The unique pointer is not modified by `*std::move(ptr)`.

> Like if I wanted the resources allocated for ptr to be freed after its value was set into val, would this achieve that?

No. You can call [`std::unique_ptr::reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) if you want the unique pointer to free the object.

---

Note that `operator*` could in principle have an overload for r-value references that does something special. See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/bMW5xrddP) for an example of one method with l-value and r-value reference overloads.

---

A bit more hand-waving....

As already mentioned, `std::move` is just a cast. You can think of `std::move(x)` as pretending that `x` would be a temporary. Now, consider that it would be rather useless to let the dereference operator make a temporary unique pointer free its resource. It's a temporary, so anyhow it will get its destructor called.